# Failed CSRF check from Vue.js to Slim Framework

Tags: vue.js, csrf, slim

I have a problem with sending a form in POST from a frontend in Vue.JS to a backend in Slim Framework.

I don't know slim very well, and I can't find the solution for the CSRF token.

Could anyone give me directions?

These are my routes, I'm not using any middleware:

```
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/operators', ApiOperator::class . ':index');
    $app->get('/products', ApiProduct::class . ':index');
    $app->get('/operators/{id}', ApiOperator::class . ':show');
    $app->post('/appointments', AppointmentController::class . ':index');
});
```

this instead the call in post via axios that I do from Vue.JS

```
    submitBooking() {
      axios.post(`${baseUri}/appointments`, this.booking)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.resetForm();
          this.step = 1;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
```

thanks to whoever can help me

fix a problem with the csrf

Comment: Have you tried this for Slim 4? https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Csrf